# Golang foreach difference

Tags: go

```
func Benchmark_foreach1(b *testing.B) {
        var test map[int]int
        test = make(map[int]int)
            for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
                        test[i] = 1
            }
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                    for i, _ := range test {
                            if test[i] != 1 {
                                    panic("ds")
                            }
                    }
            }
}

func Benchmark_foreach2(b *testing.B) {
            var test map[int]int
            test = make(map[int]int)
            for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
                    test[i] = 1
            }
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                    for _, v := range test {
                            if v != 1 {
                                    panic("heh")
                            }
                    }
            }
}
```

run with result as below

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
Benchmark_foreach1-2         500           3172323 ns/op
Benchmark_foreach2-2        1000           1707214 ns/op
```

why is foreach-2 slow?

Comment: Just the opposite: the second loop is significantly faster. `ns/op` is nanoseconds per operation, the smaller the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `Benchmark_foreach2-2` is about 2 times faster - it requires 1707214 nanoseconds per operation, and first one takes 3172323. So second one is `3172323 / 1707214 = 1.85` times faster.

Reason: second doesn't need to take value from a memory again, it already used value in `v` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `test[k]` statement in `BenchmarkForeachK` takes time to randomly read the value, so `BenchmarkForeachK` takes more time than `BenchmarkForeachV`, 9362945 ns/op versus 4213940 ns/op   .

For example,

```
package main

import "testing"

func testMap() map[int]int {
    test := make(map[int]int)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        test[i] = 1
    }
    return test
}

func BenchmarkForeachK(b *testing.B) {
    test := testMap()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for k := range test {
            if test[k] != 1 {
                panic("eh")
            }
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkForeachV(b *testing.B) {
    test := testMap()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, v := range test {
            if v != 1 {
                panic("heh")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test foreach_test.go -bench=.
BenchmarkForeachK-4    200    9362945 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkForeachV-4    300    4213940 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
```